# travis ci variables not accessible from .travis-ci.yml

Tags: travis-ci, github-pages

I am trying to deploy the build to gh pages from travis ci. But, I am not able to access the variables from within the git commands, otherwise the variables are accessible when simply trying to echo them.

`jobs:
  include:
    - stage: "lint"
      name: "Check for code smell"
      script: yarn lint
    - stage: "deploy"
      name: "Deploy to GH Pages"
      script: 
        - git config --global user.name ${Name}
        - git config --global user.email ${Email}
        - git remote rm origin
        - git remote add origin https://linux-nerd:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@${GH_REF}
        - yarn run deploy
        - echo ${Email}
        - echo $Email
        - echo https://linux-nerd:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@${GH_REF}`

The last three echos are printing correctly, but the git commands do not take the correct values.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

this is how I configure git user and email:

```
git config --global user.name "username"
git config --global user.email "email"
```

**Please not the use of "" above**

thats what u are missing in your file

Comment: I want to use the username, email and GITHUB_TOKEN from the travis-ci variables